# (Google Sheets) How can I reference a cell value (string) in the 2nd parameter of the query function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Imagine I have a string value at cell A2 = "name".

I want to use query in such a way that I can reference the value of the cell in the second parameter like this:

=QUERY(Sheet1!A:E, "select Col4 where Col3 = 'A2' ", 0)

But of course, that won't work because since the parameter is inside '', the function reads it as a string (as A2 instead of name).

How can I reference the cell itself so that it will read the value of the cell instead of 'A2'?

Answer (score 2):

*You may try:*

```js
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:E}, "select Col4 where Col3 = '"&A2&"' ", 0)
```

***OR***

```js
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:E, "select D where C = '"&A2&"' ", 0)
```

***OR***

```js
=filter(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!C:C=A2)
```